# MBP trackpad not working, but Apple (store) got it to work during reinstallation of macOS

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad

MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014, macOS Sierra 10.12.6).

My built-in trackpad can click (sometimes) but not point, scroll, zoom, or perform gestures, so I have to use a USB Logitech mouse.

I took it to Apple and after they checked some settings they were not able to get it to work. I decided to have them erase everything and reinstall macOS. During the process of them installing the OS again the Apple guy was able to use my trackpad just fine! I said Oh you fixed it. Then after it was installed it did not work again! So it must not be that it is broken inside.

I asked him how can that be?? He said when it was working it was because it was being accessed through Apple's side and it must be something in the OS preventing it from working.

I do not know if reinstalling the OS still keeps disk image checksums, folders or system preferences accessibility settings.

**What settings should I check or what Terminal commands could I use to try and get my trackpad working again?**

Comment: did he just reinstall the OSX or all your files as well.

Comment: just reinstall the OSX. I told him I did not want to keep anything because of any setting that could have been causing the problem.

Comment: I still belive the Logitech is somehow hijacking the Track pad. Check if Logitech is running.

Comment: USB Receiver:

  Product ID: 0xc52f
  Vendor ID: 0x046d  (Logitech Inc.)
  Version: 30.00
  Speed: Up to 12 Mb/sec
  Manufacturer: Logitech
  Location ID: 0x14200000 / 14
  Current Available (mA): 500
  Current Required (mA): 98
  Extra Operating Current (mA): 0

Comment: USB Device Tree /USB3.0 Bus /apple internal keyboard/trackpad. /then it says... BRCM207002 Hub /Bluetooth USB Host Controller

Comment: Thanks, now kill all Logitech from your system (and restart), do not worry you can reinstall it. See if trackpad is now working.

Comment: Thank you. I think it is caused from a combination of keys I pressed and settings I used in voiceover training.

Comment: Did you fix it ?

Comment: The easiest way to test if the trackpad is working correctly is to boot into Safe Mode (hold shift while booting).  It will prevent any 3rd party apps from loading ensuring a clean environment.  If the problem goes away, you know it's an app issue.  If it remains, it's potentially a hardware issue.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling OS X will keep your previous system preferences set up.

Trackpad could be disabled in the System Preferences Accessibility.
Since in your case you had the Logitech plugged in, the system just did what it was asked and disabled the trackpad.

> USB Receiver: Product ID: 0xc52f Vendor ID: 0x046d (Logitech Inc.)
>   Version: 30.00 Speed: Up to 12 Mb/sec Manufacturer: Logitech Location
>   ID: 0x14200000 / 14 Current Available (mA): 500 Current Required (mA):
>   98 Extra Operating Current (mA): 0

[image]

Solution: Disable the check mark in the system preferences Accessibility.

Comment: Thank you, I looked to remove any Logitech using search and found nothing named Logitech, I did then search all over the computer using key words in finder, library, system, ect with different search options. If it is there it is not named to find it.

Comment: I did uncheck the check mark in system preferences. Then started in safe mode and I got it to move, The thing is I was trying so many random taps and guestures that im not sure what worked and i cant get it to do it again.  IF I AM IN SAFE MODE do any settings that I changed like keyboard shortcuts, or accessability settings still work.

Comment: Oh, I removed the usb then started in safe mode.

Comment: so we are making progress !

Comment: Im still working on this, I did not have the Ignore built in trackpad box checked. I figured out the trackpad works perfect during a startup holding down the D key for Diagnostic Test It can move all around. I did a Safe Boot and recovery.  I want to make sure that gestures (either the ones in System Pref Trackpad, or gestures camera recognition are not involved. I do not know how yet.